# Page is reloaded inside alert window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, alert

This was suppose to get the id of the checked radio using jQuery and `$_POST['points']` and `echo` it in `add.php`

add.php:

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <form role="form" method="POST">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="1"> Leadership </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="2"> Management </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="3"> Distribution </label>
      </div>

      <div>
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['points'])) 
        {
          echo $_POST['points']." is the value";
        }
        else
          echo 'none';
      ?>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function()
{
    var value=($('input[type=radio]  [name=optradio]:checked').attr('id'));

    $.post("./add.php", {points: value}, function(data)
    {
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

However, everytime I click on a radio button, it displays an alert popup window and reloads the whole `add.php` code **INSIDE** the alert popup window instead of echo it via `$_POST['points']` in `add.php`.
The page echos `'none'` and the value at `$_POST['points']` is correct in the alert popup window.

*NOTE: The JS files are already loaded

I figured out that it echos `none` because the radio buttons are not yet checked/clicked. But the page does not load after I click a radio button but the page is reloaded inside the alert window.

Is there something I'm missing or I should've done other than alert?
OR
Is there another way of getting the id of the checked radio?

> > > > > > EDIT<<<<<<
> > > > > >             Probably most of you suggested to use .text instead of echo to display the data. What I really want to do is save the value of $_POST['points'].
> > > > > >             The value is saved but the page is reloaded inside alert window.

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <form role="form" method="POST">
      <div class="radio">
      <?php
        foreach(returnFromTable($GLOBALS['table_key_area']) as $keyarea)
        {
          echo '<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="'.$keyarea['id'].'">'.$keyarea['description'].'&nbsp</label>';
        }
      ?>
      </div>

      <div>
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['points'])) 
        {
          $x = $_POST['points'];
        }
        else
          echo 'none';
      ?>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: The server is returning you the add.php page in the post call. And you are displaying this return value in the alert box.

Comment: @M4R1KU is there other ways to return the value from jquery to php other than alert? alert return the value but reloads the page inside alert

Answer (score 1):

You need to change 2 things in your script:

1) Use `$('input[name=optradio]:checked').attr('id')` for getting Id

2) Use 'points' instead of points in post request

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function()
  {   
      var value=($('input[name=optradio]:checked').attr('id'));

      $.post("viewport.php", {'points': value}, function(data)
      {
        alert(data);
      });
  });
```

Comment: It just does the same

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ajax for this:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form role="form" method="POST">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="1"> Leadership </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="2"> Management </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="3"> Distribution </label>
      </div>

      <div class="result">
      none
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

js:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function()
{   var value = 'none';
        value = $('input[type=radio]  [name=optradio]:checked').attr('id');
    $('.result').text(value+'is the value')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a $.post call which is equivalent to the $.ajax (type: post) call, the server will return the same response as it would if you just type add.php in the url.

You don't have to make an ajax call you can just write the id with javascript/jQuery.

```
$("#some-text-container").text(value);
```

Insert this instead of the post call.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['points'])) 
  {
      echo $_POST['points']." is the value";
  }
  else
          ?>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form role="form" method="POST">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="1"> Leadership </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="2"> Management </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="3"> Distribution </label>
      </div>

      <div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: echo none since the $_POST is loaded before the radio?

Comment: @Darrius @M4R1KU The intended point was to echo the alert message only and not the rest of the html when `$_POST['points']` is set. As it works now, the default html above the $_POST check is echoed everytime ,whether in normal page load or as a response of the ajax post request.